# android need google user id as part of method to unlock feature

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, userid

My app is free and, using in-app purchases, I'd like to enable additional functionality.  To do so, I am envisioning generating an unlock code that is dependent on the current user and the current app version.  I need the first so that the same key won't work with someone else's installation (but will work for multiple devices owned by the same user).  I may not need the second, but it would give a bit more future flexibility.

To do this, I need some sort of google user id.  Is there such a thing?  If so, how do I get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google takes care of some of this for you.  It will deliver a device dependent key to each device for a user.  Your job is

1) Validate the key properly on your server

2) Make sure you return a device-specific authorization value from the server so users cannot just copy data files around.

3) On the device, use the authorization value to enable things.

Validating the key is easy but do make sure you do it on a server.  The problem is identifying the device.  Google and its partners dropped the ball a bit on that.  Tim Bray has a blog article at http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html that discusses the problem.  I recommend using the ANDROID_ID despite his reservations.  I have doubts about the security of his other proposal but haven't done a full analysis.   Definitely stay away from anything network related (IMSI, IMEI, ESN, ...).  I also cache the device identifier used and make sure it doesn't change.

Personally, I scramble the data needed to unlock my features in my app.  When I get a valid transaction, I compute a key that can be combined with the device id to unlock the data.  It is far from perfect but seems to work.  I accept that I will be hacked - I just don't want it to be obvious.

If you want a per-version key, then you need to do a RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS and re-validate at the server any time the version changes.

Comment: Give me a bit of time to research all this. I was hoping to do this without a server (at least for now), but I suppose that is better because it makes it hard to hack the app to enable the features.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: If you do things on the device, then a whole new range of attacks open up.  On some platforms, there are hacking utilities available that are purely based on people redirecting DNS away from the store and fudging values. I can't remember if Google Play is one of those but I don't see why it wouldn't be.  I know I've had people try them against my app and fail because I had a server.  Of course, I don't know how many tried another way and succeeded :)

Comment: One more minor comment - I'm paranoid - I actually have two different servers on different hosting companies.  If one goes down, I don't worry as I put failover code in my app.  Ugly but it lets me sleep at night (and use the cheapest hosting companies).

Comment: This might turn into a longer discussion - feel free to contact me at perih kotatko com.  I (or you) can post the meaningful results here, afterwards.  Question: It sounds like you are generating a unique key on a server, sending it to the device.  How, then, do you validate the key?  Does the app have to check with the server each time it starts up?

Comment: "It will deliver a device dependent key to each device for a user" -- If a user gets a new device, if you tie the purchase to the device, the user will no longer be able to access his/her previous purchases.  I think you need to tie the purchase to a unique user token that is tied to the user's google account on the device.

Comment: @Gino - when the user gets a new device, Google will issue new receipt information for each of the user's purchases that is valid for that device.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest another approach - no better, just different.  Use a flag to indicate whether to allow or not running the upgrade features.  Periodically validate with the in-app billing apis whether the user has purchased the upgrade.  If not, reset the flag.

The user can hack the flag, but sooner or later it will be reset, blocking use of the features.

To truely break this method, the user would have to reverse engineer the code and bypass checking the flag.  I doubt most people would bother with that, but what do I know?